# flutter how do I use the listener onPointerPanZoomUpdate?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm wanting to use onPointerPanZoomUpdate
on the listener widget
refer - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Listener-class.html

but when put this widget into my widget tree I don't get the option to use onPointerPanZoomUpdate. The documentation has it as a property, so I assumed I should be able to set it.

I was wanting to use this to get two finger panning working and to be able to tell when it was iPad interaction, which I want as two finger interaction, or if it was windows interaction. For windows I was wanting mouse interaction (i.e. one point).

Comment: you need flutter `v3.3` for that to work - most likely your version is older than 3.3

Comment: thanks for that pskink, yep I was not 3.3
I can see them now but they are not firing is there something else I need to do here. Seems strange. I've used the demo project and just added a listener around the center widget.
```
      body: Listener(
        onPointerDown: onPointerDownEvent,
        onPointerPanZoomStart: onPointerPanZoomStartEvent,
        onPointerPanZoomUpdate: onPointerPanZoomUpdateEvent,
        child: Center(
...
```

Comment: the onPointerDown works just not the onPointerPanZoomStart and Update.

Comment: `onPointerPanZoom*` callbacks work with trackpad only

Comment: thanks for that pskink. Back to the drawing board for me then. Thanks for you input, much appreciated.

Comment: If you want two finger gestures use `GestureDetector` instead, more: https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart#L120

Comment: yer gesture almost works. For iPad I need two finger panning and zooming and one finger lasso selection. For windows I need left mouse down and drag for panning, mouse wheel for zooming and shift left mouse down for lasso select. With onPanStart I don't have the option to see how many points are being used, so I need a way to figure that out, if its a lasso that I need to do or a pan. I could be missing something here to tell me the number of points.

Comment: in onScaleStart increment fingers, in onScaleEnd decrement fingers

Comment: thanks pskink. that is almost there :) . Unfortunately doesn't have the kind of interaction, so I will need to pull this from somewhere else (iPad or windows). Thanks for you input, much appreciated.